# LWJGL - everything is gone after loading font

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, truetype

I had a weird problem when I tried to display some text on the screen. I followed this tutorial [Slick Util - TrueType Fonts for LWJGL](http://www.ninjacave.com/slickutil3). The text was displayed properly but everything else was gone. This happens even when no text is rendered. And it will go back to normal when I remove the code to load the font.

Here is my code:(The rectangle won't show when I have this line of code: this.font = this.loadDefaultFont(30);)

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_BLEND;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_MODELVIEW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_PROJECTION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBlendFunc;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearColor;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor4f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnd;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glOrtho;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex2i;

import java.awt.Font;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;

public class TrueTypeFontDemo {
    private TrueTypeFont font;

    public TrueTypeFontDemo() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setTitle("TrueTypeFont Demo");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        this.font = this.loadDefaultFont(30);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            this.font.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world", Color.red);

            glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
                glVertex2i(500, 500);
                glVertex2i(500, 50);
                glVertex2i(600, 50);
                glVertex2i(600, 500);
            }
            glEnd();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    private TrueTypeFont loadDefaultFont(int size) {
        // load a default java font
        Font awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, size);
        return new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TrueTypeFontDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that `loadDefaultFont (...)` is leaking some OpenGL state. You might try: `glPushAttrib (GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS)` before calling it, and `glPopAttrib ()` immediately after, to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Just tried glPushAttrib() and glPopAttrib(). Now everything else does appear but the font doesn't work correctly. All the text will become a solid color rectangle.

Comment: At least we know it's a state issue now. Without seeing the implementation for `org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont`, I can only guess your problem has to do with the `GL_TEXTURE_2D` state.

Comment: GLScene had same problems, font loadin leaked states and I had to patch it.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman It indeed has something to do with `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. I need to disable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` before drawing anything else and enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` again to render text.

Comment: Isn't TTF supposed to be a vector font not a bitmap font? Why would it have something to do with texture?

Comment: The individual fonts are stroked that way, but they are generally rendered using a specific set of characteristics (e.g. bold + italic) and put into a sprite sheet for the simplest of font rendering in OpenGL. More sophisticated systems will actually render text using FreeType, but it still winds up a stretched texture in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Slick-Util as a library, try adding `TextureImpl.bindNone();` after every call to render text.